# Best ways to transform a text on an html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to replace some words on an HTML page with links, i.e. "linkify" these words. I have an array of identifier descriptors, like this:

```
  var symbols_desc = [
    {
      id: 'id_one',
      name: 'struct my_struct_one',
    },
    {
      id: 'id_two',
      name: 'my_name_two',
    },
    /* ... */
  ]
```

So in certain areas of HTML page I need to transform all occurrences of `struct my_struct_one` to `<a href="#id_one">struct my_struct_one</a>`, etc.

I'm not an expert in the Web field, so, I use probably the dumbest way: I update HTML by means of jQuery. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".some-class1, .some-class2").each(function() {
    var o = $(this);

    symbols_desc.forEach(function(desc){

      o.html(
        o.html().replace(
          new RegExp('(\\b' + desc.name + '\\b)', 'g'),
          '<a class="symb-link" href="#' + desc.id + '">$1</a>'
        )
      );
    });

  });
});
```

It works, but it is unacceptably slow. There are about 70 identifiers, HTML page is about 200 KB, and it takes about 5 seconds.

Given the complexity and awesomeness of some Web applications that I use from time to time, I'm sure there should be better ways to perform this simple task. I'd be glad to hear your suggestions.

Comment: I have some ideas that would improve the speed but i don't know for sure without testing. Would you mind providing the html and the symbols array?

Comment: at least I suggest you to make a variable from `o.html()`, because you call a function in a loop. And one more - use one single class for this action

Comment: @EricGuan, here is a zip file: http://dmitryfrank.com/usr/tmp/linkify_test.zip , see html file in `mongoose/docs/index.html`, and js file: `static/js/linkify.js`

Comment: @Undefitied (and upvoters), not sure how that would make things better, given that the result of `o.html()` changes at each loop iteration.

Comment: I don't think the forEach is the bottleneck, but it's worth mentioning that it's about 4 times slower than a normal  for(var i = 0; i < symbols_desc.length; i++). Also, like @Undefitied said, create a `var foo = o.html()` above the loop.

Comment: @dannyjolie, result of `o.html()` changes at each loop iteration. Creating `var foo = o.html()` would break the behaviour. Thanks for the hint about the for loop, but yeah, it's negligible here.

Comment: Depending on your actual requirement you might consider better tools than jQuery. Any decent text editor can do the same job without any coding at all.

Comment: @simone, that might be the case if I need to replace *all* occurrences on the whole html page. But I need that only in certain fields of the page, and jQuery does that filtering for me: `$(".some-class1, .some-class2")`

Comment: @Dmitry , u can check this stuff i did here, this might help u http://jsfiddle.net/wQns7/1640/ , i been fiddling around :)

Comment: I provided an answer that should boost the performance. No need to loop through the dictionary and repeat the regex operation ~70 times when once will do just fine :)

Comment: @rockStar, thanks for trying to help, but your snippet wraps the whole element whose class is `some1`; but I need to wrap just a text `struct my_struct_one`.

Comment: Using the wrapInner() it only wraps the text which u r looking for..see it once more..else if its not correct, i tried to help :-)

Comment: Did you test my answer with your 200kB document? I'm curious about how it performs :)

Answer (score 2):

In your case I think all we have do is to change comfortable `forEach` to simple `for` and use more variables, so please try:

```
$(".some-class1, .some-class2").each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html();

    for (var i = 0; i < symbols_desc.length; i++) {
        html.replace(
            new RegExp('(\\b' + symbols_desc[i].name + '\\b)', 'g'),
            '<a class="symb-link" href="#' + symbols_desc[i].id + '">$1</a>'
        );
    }

    $(this).html(html);
});
```

Comment: Ahh, now I understand what exactly do you mean about using a variable. For now I just tried to avoid using `o.html()` that much, and it provided a huge performance boost. How could I miss it. Thank you!

Comment: glad that it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

First off, no need to use jQuery. It probably contributes to slowing everything down. Get your HTML areas by using

`var fooElements = document.querySelectorAll('.someclass1, .someclass2')`

This returns a nodelist, and array like object, that can be looped using a normal `for`.

Also, your dictionary doesn't have to be an array.

```
var symbols_desc = {
  'id_one' : 'struct my_struct_one',
  'id_two' : 'my_name_two'
}
```

Now we can have one regex to replace everything in one go per html element you want to work on, instead of looping n * m times

```
var fooRegex = new RegExp(Object.keys(symbols_desc).join("|"),"gi");
```

All that remains is to do the actual work

```
for(var i = 0; i < fooElements.length; i++){
  fooElements[i].innerHTML = fooElements[i].innerHTML.replace(fooRegex,function(matchedString){
    return mapObj[matchedString.toLowerCase()];
  });
}
```

Working example, it should be pretty fast:

```js
var dictionary = {
  'mouse': 'cat',
  'dog': 'mouse',
  'horse': 'dog',
  'cat': 'horse'
}

var fooElements = document.querySelectorAll('.some-class1, .some-class2');

var fooRegex = new RegExp(Object.keys(dictionary).join("|"), "gi");

for (var i = 0; i < fooElements.length; i++) {
  fooElements[i].innerHTML = fooElements[i].innerHTML.replace(fooRegex, function(matchedString) {
    return dictionary[matchedString.toLowerCase()];
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="some-class1">
  Dog, cat, mouse
</div>

<div class="some-class2">
  Horse, cat, dog
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer.